# Jxbrowser doesn't show up

Tags: java, swing, view, jpanel, jxbrowser

I'm using java swing editor 
created a frame dropped a  tappedpane on it 
then dropped 4 panels, so I have 4 taps
the panel that I need to view the browser on is jpanel3
so I dropped a button and wrote this code inside of it
when I run the program and press that button I get no errors just no view
imported everything correctly and the license is valid

```
enter code here
```

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       Browser browser = new Browser();

```
   BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

   jPanel3.add(view);

   browser.loadURL("https://google.com");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the issue is in default `FlowLayout` in `jPanel3`. Please try the following solution:

```java
jPanel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
jPanel3.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```